# How do I check if a network is contained in another network in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking

How can I check if a network is wholly contained in another network in Python, e.g. if `10.11.12.0/24` is in `10.11.0.0/16`?

I've tried using `ipaddress` but it doesn't work:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> ipaddress.ip_network('10.11.12.0/24') in ipaddress.ip_network('10.11.0.0/16')
False
```

Comment: `ipaddress.ip_network('10.11.12.0/24').overlaps(ipaddress.ip_network('10.11.0.0/16'))`?

Comment: Related: https://bugs.python.org/issue20825

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: this returns `True` in case you swap the networks.

Comment: `A= Primary Net(10.4.0.0)`, `B=Member of A(75.85.45.0)` No WAY ! if you are member of `A`, member `B` use friends example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Starting from Python [3.7.0](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#ipaddress) you can use the [`subnet_of()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Network.subnet_of) and [`supernet_of()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Network.supernet_of) methods of `ipaddress.IPv6Network` and `ipaddress.IPv4Network` for network containment tests:

```
>>> from ipaddress import ip_network
>>> a = ip_network('192.168.1.0/24')
>>> b = ip_network('192.168.1.128/30')
>>> b.subnet_of(a)
True
>>> a.supernet_of(b)
True
```

If you have a Python version prior to 3.7.0, you can just copy the method's [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Lib/ipaddress.py#L976) from the later version of the module.

Answer (score 7):

```
import ipaddress

def is_subnet_of(a, b):
   """
   Returns boolean: is `a` a subnet of `b`?
   """
   a = ipaddress.ip_network(a)
   b = ipaddress.ip_network(b)
   a_len = a.prefixlen
   b_len = b.prefixlen
   return a_len >= b_len and a.supernet(a_len - b_len) == b
```

then

```
is_subnet_of("10.11.12.0/24", "10.11.0.0/16")   # => True
```

Comment: now built-in in module ipaddress:  `ipaddress.ip_network(u'10.11.12.0/24').subnet_of(ipaddress.ip_network(u'10.11.0.0/16')) == True`

Comment: @Francois Really? What version of Python? I don't see it [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ipaddress.html?highlight=ipaddress#network-objects).

Comment: tested with Python 2.7.9

Answer (score 5):

Try  [netaddr](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netaddr) as below-

**Check if a network is in another**

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork,IPAddress

if IPNetwork("10.11.12.0/24") in IPNetwork("10.11.0.0/16"):
    print "Yes it is!"
```

**Check if an IP is in a network**

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork,IPAddress

if IPAddress("10.11.12.0") in IPNetwork("10.11.0.0/16"):
    print "Yes it is!"
```

Comment: This seems like a much better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to implement such a check. Reading the documentation of [ipaddress module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html), I found the function `overlaps()`. It works. Code example:

```
import ipaddress
from ipaddress import IPv4Network

supernet = IPv4Network('10.0.0.0/8')
net = IPv4Network('11.0.10.0/30')
print(net.overlaps(supernet))
```

Comment: tihs example does not demonstrate a solution to the question ; and it is wrong anyway since `overlaps` returns true even if `net` is not wholly contained inside `supernet` (see comment of @planetp above)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the ipaddress module does not provide a simple function to check whether a network is contained in another network. I managed to solve this problem as follows:

`ip1 = '10.0.0.0/24'
ip2 = '10.0.0.22'
ipaddress.ip_network(ip2) in ipaddress.ip_network(ip1).subnets(new_prefix=ipaddress.ip_network(ip2).prefixlen)`